# Extract meter levels from audio file

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer, audiotoolbox

I need to extract audio meter levels from a file so I can render the levels before playing the audio. I know `AVAudioPlayer` can get this information while playing the audio file through

```
func averagePower(forChannel channelNumber: Int) -> Float.
```

But in my case I would like to obtain an `[Float]` of meter levels beforehand.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Swift 4

It takes on an iPhone:

- **0.538s** to process an `8MByte` mp3 player with a `4min47s` duration, and `44,100` sampling rate
- **0.170s** to process an `712KByte` mp3 player with a `22s` duration, and `44,100` sampling rate
- **0.089s** to process `caf`file created by converting the file above using this command `afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 audio.mp3 audio.caf` in the terminal.

Let's begin:

**A)** Declare this class that is going to hold the necessary information about the audio asset:

```
/// Holds audio information used for building waveforms
final class AudioContext {
    
    /// The audio asset URL used to load the context
    public let audioURL: URL
    
    /// Total number of samples in loaded asset
    public let totalSamples: Int
    
    /// Loaded asset
    public let asset: AVAsset
    
    // Loaded assetTrack
    public let assetTrack: AVAssetTrack
    
    private init(audioURL: URL, totalSamples: Int, asset: AVAsset, assetTrack: AVAssetTrack) {
        self.audioURL = audioURL
        self.totalSamples = totalSamples
        self.asset = asset
        self.assetTrack = assetTrack
    }
    
    public static func load(fromAudioURL audioURL: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (_ audioContext: AudioContext?) -> ()) {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: audioURL, options: [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: NSNumber(value: true as Bool)])
        
        guard let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first else {
            fatalError("Couldn't load AVAssetTrack")
        }
        
        asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: ["duration"]) {
            var error: NSError?
            let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "duration", error: &error)
            switch status {
            case .loaded:
                guard
                    let formatDescriptions = assetTrack.formatDescriptions as? [CMAudioFormatDescription],
                    let audioFormatDesc = formatDescriptions.first,
                    let asbd = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(audioFormatDesc)
                    else { break }
                
                let totalSamples = Int((asbd.pointee.mSampleRate) * Float64(asset.duration.value) / Float64(asset.duration.timescale))
                let audioContext = AudioContext(audioURL: audioURL, totalSamples: totalSamples, asset: asset, assetTrack: assetTrack)
                completionHandler(audioContext)
                return
                
            case .failed, .cancelled, .loading, .unknown:
                print("Couldn't load asset: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            }
            
            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

We are going to use its asynchronous function `load`, and handle its result to a completion handler.

**B)** Import `AVFoundation` and `Accelerate` in your view controller:

```
import AVFoundation
import Accelerate
```

**C)** Declare the noise level in your view controller (in dB):

```
let noiseFloor: Float = -80
```

For example, anything less than `-80dB` will be considered as silence.

**D)** The following function takes an audio context and produces the desired dB powers. `targetSamples` is by default set to 100, you can change that to suit your UI needs:

```
func render(audioContext: AudioContext?, targetSamples: Int = 100) -> [Float]{
    guard let audioContext = audioContext else {
        fatalError("Couldn't create the audioContext")
    }
    
    let sampleRange: CountableRange<Int> = 0..<audioContext.totalSamples
    
    guard let reader = try? AVAssetReader(asset: audioContext.asset)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't initialize the AVAssetReader")
    }
    
    reader.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTime(value: Int64(sampleRange.lowerBound), timescale: audioContext.asset.duration.timescale),
                                   duration: CMTime(value: Int64(sampleRange.count), timescale: audioContext.asset.duration.timescale))
    
    let outputSettingsDict: [String : Any] = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
        AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false,
        AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
        AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: false
    ]
    
    let readerOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: audioContext.assetTrack,
                                                outputSettings: outputSettingsDict)
    readerOutput.alwaysCopiesSampleData = false
    reader.add(readerOutput)
    
    var channelCount = 1
    let formatDescriptions = audioContext.assetTrack.formatDescriptions as! [CMAudioFormatDescription]
    for item in formatDescriptions {
        guard let fmtDesc = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(item) else {
            fatalError("Couldn't get the format description")
        }
        channelCount = Int(fmtDesc.pointee.mChannelsPerFrame)
    }
    
    let samplesPerPixel = max(1, channelCount * sampleRange.count / targetSamples)
    let filter = [Float](repeating: 1.0 / Float(samplesPerPixel), count: samplesPerPixel)
    
    var outputSamples = [Float]()
    var sampleBuffer = Data()
    
    // 16-bit samples
    reader.startReading()
    defer { reader.cancelReading() }
    
    while reader.status == .reading {
        guard let readSampleBuffer = readerOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer(),
            let readBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(readSampleBuffer) else {
                break
        }
        // Append audio sample buffer into our current sample buffer
        var readBufferLength = 0
        var readBufferPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?
        CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer(readBuffer, 0, &readBufferLength, nil, &readBufferPointer)
        sampleBuffer.append(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: readBufferPointer, count: readBufferLength))
        CMSampleBufferInvalidate(readSampleBuffer)
        
        let totalSamples = sampleBuffer.count / MemoryLayout<Int16>.size
        let downSampledLength = totalSamples / samplesPerPixel
        let samplesToProcess = downSampledLength * samplesPerPixel
        
        guard samplesToProcess > 0 else { continue }
        
        processSamples(fromData: &sampleBuffer,
                       outputSamples: &outputSamples,
                       samplesToProcess: samplesToProcess,
                       downSampledLength: downSampledLength,
                       samplesPerPixel: samplesPerPixel,
                       filter: filter)
        //print("Status: \(reader.status)")
    }
    
    // Process the remaining samples at the end which didn't fit into samplesPerPixel
    let samplesToProcess = sampleBuffer.count / MemoryLayout<Int16>.size
    if samplesToProcess > 0 {
        let downSampledLength = 1
        let samplesPerPixel = samplesToProcess
        let filter = [Float](repeating: 1.0 / Float(samplesPerPixel), count: samplesPerPixel)
        
        processSamples(fromData: &sampleBuffer,
                       outputSamples: &outputSamples,
                       samplesToProcess: samplesToProcess,
                       downSampledLength: downSampledLength,
                       samplesPerPixel: samplesPerPixel,
                       filter: filter)
        //print("Status: \(reader.status)")
    }
    
    // if (reader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusFailed || reader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusUnknown)
    guard reader.status == .completed else {
        fatalError("Couldn't read the audio file")
    }
    
    return outputSamples
}
```

**E)** `render` uses this function to down-sample the data from the audio file, and convert to decibels:

```
func processSamples(fromData sampleBuffer: inout Data,
                    outputSamples: inout [Float],
                    samplesToProcess: Int,
                    downSampledLength: Int,
                    samplesPerPixel: Int,
                    filter: [Float]) {
    sampleBuffer.withUnsafeBytes { (samples: UnsafePointer<Int16>) in
        var processingBuffer = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: samplesToProcess)
        
        let sampleCount = vDSP_Length(samplesToProcess)
        
        //Convert 16bit int samples to floats
        vDSP_vflt16(samples, 1, &processingBuffer, 1, sampleCount)
        
        //Take the absolute values to get amplitude
        vDSP_vabs(processingBuffer, 1, &processingBuffer, 1, sampleCount)
        
        //get the corresponding dB, and clip the results
        getdB(from: &processingBuffer)
        
        //Downsample and average
        var downSampledData = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: downSampledLength)
        vDSP_desamp(processingBuffer,
                    vDSP_Stride(samplesPerPixel),
                    filter, &downSampledData,
                    vDSP_Length(downSampledLength),
                    vDSP_Length(samplesPerPixel))
        
        //Remove processed samples
        sampleBuffer.removeFirst(samplesToProcess * MemoryLayout<Int16>.size)
        
        outputSamples += downSampledData
    }
}
```

**F)** Which in turn calls this function that gets the corresponding dB, and clips the results to `[noiseFloor, 0]`:

```
func getdB(from normalizedSamples: inout [Float]) {
    // Convert samples to a log scale
    var zero: Float = 32768.0
    vDSP_vdbcon(normalizedSamples, 1, &zero, &normalizedSamples, 1, vDSP_Length(normalizedSamples.count), 1)
    
    //Clip to [noiseFloor, 0]
    var ceil: Float = 0.0
    var noiseFloorMutable = noiseFloor
    vDSP_vclip(normalizedSamples, 1, &noiseFloorMutable, &ceil, &normalizedSamples, 1, vDSP_Length(normalizedSamples.count))
}
```

**G)** Finally you can get the waveform of the audio like so:

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "audio", ofType:"mp3") else {
    fatalError("Couldn't find the file path")
}
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
var outputArray : [Float] = []
AudioContext.load(fromAudioURL: url, completionHandler: { audioContext in
    guard let audioContext = audioContext else {
        fatalError("Couldn't create the audioContext")
    }
    outputArray = self.render(audioContext: audioContext, targetSamples: 300)
})
```

Don't forget that `AudioContext.load(fromAudioURL:)` is asynchronous.

This solution is synthesized from [this repo](https://github.com/fulldecent/FDWaveformView) by **William Entriken**. All credit goes to him.

---

### Swift 5

Here is the same code updated to Swift 5 syntax:

```
import AVFoundation
import Accelerate

/// Holds audio information used for building waveforms
final class AudioContext {
    
    /// The audio asset URL used to load the context
    public let audioURL: URL
    
    /// Total number of samples in loaded asset
    public let totalSamples: Int
    
    /// Loaded asset
    public let asset: AVAsset
    
    // Loaded assetTrack
    public let assetTrack: AVAssetTrack
    
    private init(audioURL: URL, totalSamples: Int, asset: AVAsset, assetTrack: AVAssetTrack) {
        self.audioURL = audioURL
        self.totalSamples = totalSamples
        self.asset = asset
        self.assetTrack = assetTrack
    }
    
    public static func load(fromAudioURL audioURL: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (_ audioContext: AudioContext?) -> ()) {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: audioURL, options: [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: NSNumber(value: true as Bool)])
        
        guard let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first else {
            fatalError("Couldn't load AVAssetTrack")
        }
        
        asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: ["duration"]) {
            var error: NSError?
            let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "duration", error: &error)
            switch status {
            case .loaded:
                guard
                    let formatDescriptions = assetTrack.formatDescriptions as? [CMAudioFormatDescription],
                    let audioFormatDesc = formatDescriptions.first,
                    let asbd = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(audioFormatDesc)
                    else { break }
                
                let totalSamples = Int((asbd.pointee.mSampleRate) * Float64(asset.duration.value) / Float64(asset.duration.timescale))
                let audioContext = AudioContext(audioURL: audioURL, totalSamples: totalSamples, asset: asset, assetTrack: assetTrack)
                completionHandler(audioContext)
                return
                
            case .failed, .cancelled, .loading, .unknown:
                print("Couldn't load asset: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            }
            
            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    }
}

let noiseFloor: Float = -80

func render(audioContext: AudioContext?, targetSamples: Int = 100) -> [Float]{
    guard let audioContext = audioContext else {
        fatalError("Couldn't create the audioContext")
    }
    
    let sampleRange: CountableRange<Int> = 0..<audioContext.totalSamples
    
    guard let reader = try? AVAssetReader(asset: audioContext.asset)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't initialize the AVAssetReader")
    }
    
    reader.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTime(value: Int64(sampleRange.lowerBound), timescale: audioContext.asset.duration.timescale),
                                   duration: CMTime(value: Int64(sampleRange.count), timescale: audioContext.asset.duration.timescale))
    
    let outputSettingsDict: [String : Any] = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
        AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false,
        AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
        AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: false
    ]
    
    let readerOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: audioContext.assetTrack,
                                                outputSettings: outputSettingsDict)
    readerOutput.alwaysCopiesSampleData = false
    reader.add(readerOutput)
    
    var channelCount = 1
    let formatDescriptions = audioContext.assetTrack.formatDescriptions as! [CMAudioFormatDescription]
    for item in formatDescriptions {
        guard let fmtDesc = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(item) else {
            fatalError("Couldn't get the format description")
        }
        channelCount = Int(fmtDesc.pointee.mChannelsPerFrame)
    }
    
    let samplesPerPixel = max(1, channelCount * sampleRange.count / targetSamples)
    let filter = [Float](repeating: 1.0 / Float(samplesPerPixel), count: samplesPerPixel)
    
    var outputSamples = [Float]()
    var sampleBuffer = Data()
    
    // 16-bit samples
    reader.startReading()
    defer { reader.cancelReading() }
    
    while reader.status == .reading {
        guard let readSampleBuffer = readerOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer(),
            let readBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(readSampleBuffer) else {
                break
        }
        // Append audio sample buffer into our current sample buffer
        var readBufferLength = 0
        var readBufferPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?
        CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer(readBuffer,
                                    atOffset: 0,
                                    lengthAtOffsetOut: &readBufferLength,
                                    totalLengthOut: nil,
                                    dataPointerOut: &readBufferPointer)
        sampleBuffer.append(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: readBufferPointer, count: readBufferLength))
        CMSampleBufferInvalidate(readSampleBuffer)
        
        let totalSamples = sampleBuffer.count / MemoryLayout<Int16>.size
        let downSampledLength = totalSamples / samplesPerPixel
        let samplesToProcess = downSampledLength * samplesPerPixel
        
        guard samplesToProcess > 0 else { continue }
        
        processSamples(fromData: &sampleBuffer,
                       outputSamples: &outputSamples,
                       samplesToProcess: samplesToProcess,
                       downSampledLength: downSampledLength,
                       samplesPerPixel: samplesPerPixel,
                       filter: filter)
        //print("Status: \(reader.status)")
    }
    
    // Process the remaining samples at the end which didn't fit into samplesPerPixel
    let samplesToProcess = sampleBuffer.count / MemoryLayout<Int16>.size
    if samplesToProcess > 0 {
        let downSampledLength = 1
        let samplesPerPixel = samplesToProcess
        let filter = [Float](repeating: 1.0 / Float(samplesPerPixel), count: samplesPerPixel)
        
        processSamples(fromData: &sampleBuffer,
                       outputSamples: &outputSamples,
                       samplesToProcess: samplesToProcess,
                       downSampledLength: downSampledLength,
                       samplesPerPixel: samplesPerPixel,
                       filter: filter)
        //print("Status: \(reader.status)")
    }
    
    // if (reader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusFailed || reader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusUnknown)
    guard reader.status == .completed else {
        fatalError("Couldn't read the audio file")
    }
    
    return outputSamples
}

func processSamples(fromData sampleBuffer: inout Data,
                    outputSamples: inout [Float],
                    samplesToProcess: Int,
                    downSampledLength: Int,
                    samplesPerPixel: Int,
                    filter: [Float]) {
    
    sampleBuffer.withUnsafeBytes { (samples: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in
        var processingBuffer = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: samplesToProcess)
        
        let sampleCount = vDSP_Length(samplesToProcess)
        
        //Create an UnsafePointer<Int16> from samples
        let unsafeBufferPointer = samples.bindMemory(to: Int16.self)
        let unsafePointer = unsafeBufferPointer.baseAddress!
        
        //Convert 16bit int samples to floats
        vDSP_vflt16(unsafePointer, 1, &processingBuffer, 1, sampleCount)
        
        //Take the absolute values to get amplitude
        vDSP_vabs(processingBuffer, 1, &processingBuffer, 1, sampleCount)
        
        //get the corresponding dB, and clip the results
        getdB(from: &processingBuffer)
        
        //Downsample and average
        var downSampledData = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: downSampledLength)
        vDSP_desamp(processingBuffer,
                    vDSP_Stride(samplesPerPixel),
                    filter, &downSampledData,
                    vDSP_Length(downSampledLength),
                    vDSP_Length(samplesPerPixel))
        
        //Remove processed samples
        sampleBuffer.removeFirst(samplesToProcess * MemoryLayout<Int16>.size)
        
        outputSamples += downSampledData
    }
}

func getdB(from normalizedSamples: inout [Float]) {
    // Convert samples to a log scale
    var zero: Float = 32768.0
    vDSP_vdbcon(normalizedSamples, 1, &zero, &normalizedSamples, 1, vDSP_Length(normalizedSamples.count), 1)
    
    //Clip to [noiseFloor, 0]
    var ceil: Float = 0.0
    var noiseFloorMutable = noiseFloor
    vDSP_vclip(normalizedSamples, 1, &noiseFloorMutable, &ceil, &normalizedSamples, 1, vDSP_Length(normalizedSamples.count))
}
```

---

### Old solution

Here is a function you could use to pre-render the meter levels of an audio file without playing it:

```
func averagePowers(audioFileURL: URL, forChannel channelNumber: Int, completionHandler: @escaping(_ success: [Float]) -> ()) {
    let audioFile = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: audioFileURL)
    let audioFilePFormat = audioFile.processingFormat
    let audioFileLength = audioFile.length
    
    //Set the size of frames to read from the audio file, you can adjust this to your liking
    let frameSizeToRead = Int(audioFilePFormat.sampleRate/20)
    
    //This is to how many frames/portions we're going to divide the audio file
    let numberOfFrames = Int(audioFileLength)/frameSizeToRead
    
    //Create a pcm buffer the size of a frame
    guard let audioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFilePFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(frameSizeToRead)) else {
        fatalError("Couldn't create the audio buffer")
    }
    
    //Do the calculations in a background thread, if you don't want to block the main thread for larger audio files
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        
        //This is the array to be returned
        var returnArray : [Float] = [Float]()
        
        //We're going to read the audio file, frame by frame
        for i in 0..<numberOfFrames {
            
            //Change the position from which we are reading the audio file, since each frame starts from a different position in the audio file
            audioFile.framePosition = AVAudioFramePosition(i * frameSizeToRead)
            
            //Read the frame from the audio file
            try! audioFile.read(into: audioBuffer, frameCount: AVAudioFrameCount(frameSizeToRead))
            
            //Get the data from the chosen channel
            let channelData = audioBuffer.floatChannelData![channelNumber]
            
            //This is the array of floats
            let arr = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start:channelData, count: frameSizeToRead))
            
            //Calculate the mean value of the absolute values
            let meanValue = arr.reduce(0, {$0 + abs($1)})/Float(arr.count)
            
            //Calculate the dB power (You can adjust this), if average is less than 0.000_000_01 we limit it to -160.0
            let dbPower: Float = meanValue > 0.000_000_01 ? 20 * log10(meanValue) : -160.0
            
            //append the db power in the current frame to the returnArray
            returnArray.append(dbPower)
        }
        
        //Return the dBPowers
        completionHandler(returnArray)
    }
}
```

And you can call it like so:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "audio.mp3", ofType:nil)!
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
averagePowers(audioFileURL: url, forChannel: 0, completionHandler: { array in
    //Use the array
})
```

Using instruments, this solution makes high cpu usage during 1.2 seconds, takes about 5 seconds to return to the main thread with the `returnArray`, and up to 10 seconds when on *low battery mode*.

Comment: Number of samples is the number of floats you want to get in the result array

Comment: @PeterWarbo if you want to get the data from all channels I could add a simple adjustment...

Comment: But isn't that output depending on the audio file length? If it's one minute I can expect the output to be a larger number of samples than if the length is 10 seconds? I don't see how the caller can decide how many samples to receive? It should be dependent on the audio length should it not?

Comment: It's up to you, If you want to have a fixed frame size, then it's doable (In this code, I supposed that the number of bars you want to visualize is fixed, not the duration of the frame). Do you want me to adjust it for you?

Comment: Ideally I would like to receive the same result from running `AVAudioPlayer`s `func averagePower(forChannel channelNumber: Int) -> Float` (that doesn't require me to input `numberOfFrames`)

Comment: I've updated the code to your liking. `let frameSizeToRead = Int(audioFilePFormat.sampleRate)` is just a choice, you could adapt it to your use case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179856/discussion-between-peter-warbo-and-carpsen90).

Comment: How to get it without the avAudiofile with a live AVAudioPCMBuffer?

Comment: @ielyamani I keep getting an error on this line for Swift 5 and cannot figure out how to resolve this.

`sampleBuffer.withUnsafeBytes { (samples: UnsafePointer<Int16>) in`

Comment: @JoshuaHart: I've included the Swift 5 syntax. All you had to do was to convert an `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` to an `UnsafePointer<Int16>`.

Comment: It crashes under `sampleBuffer.removeFirst(samplesToProcess * MemoryLayout<Int16>.size)` with `Thread 17: Fatal error: Can't remove more items from a collection than it contains`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AlexandruMotoc I had mistakenly pasted the `sampleBuffer.withUnsafeBytes` block of code twice. It is now fixed. Thanks!

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you @ielyamani. Curious however why in this guard there's an OR check for `true`. Is that redundant?
`guard reader.status == .completed || true else {`

Comment: Why are you doing this `let sampleRange: CountableRange<Int> = 0..<audioContext.totalSamples/3` (specifically the `/3` part). For me this outputted one third of what I actually needed (the audio is me counting to 10, and it only gets to 4). Removing this fixed it.

Comment: I am super confused on how to get the swift 5 code to run, what function do I call?

Comment: how can I get a full audio DB array?

Answer (score 13):

First of all, this is heavy operation, so it will take some OS time and resources to accomplish this. In below example I will use standard frame rates and sampling, but you should really sample far far less if you for example only want to display bars as an indications

OK so you don't need to play sound to analyze it. So in this i will not use `AVAudioPlayer` at all I assume that I will take track as `URL`:

```
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "example3.mp3", ofType:nil)!
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
```

Then I will use [AVAudioFile](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiofile) to get track information into [AVAudioPCMBuffer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiopcmbuffer). Whenever you have it in buffer you have all information regarding your track:

```
func buffer(url: URL) {
    do {
        let track = try AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
        let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat:.pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate:track.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: track.fileFormat.channelCount,  interleaved: false)
        let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format!, frameCapacity: UInt32(track.length))!
        try track.read(into : buffer, frameCount:UInt32(track.length))
        self.analyze(buffer: buffer)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

As you may notice there is `analyze` method for it. You should have close to [floatChannelData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiopcmbuffer/1386212-floatchanneldata) variable in your buffer. It's a plain data so you'll need to parse it. I will post a method and below explain this:

```
func analyze(buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer) {
    let channelCount = Int(buffer.format.channelCount)
    let frameLength = Int(buffer.frameLength)
    var result = Array(repeating: [Float](repeatElement(0, count: frameLength)), count: channelCount)
    for channel in 0..<channelCount {
        for sampleIndex in 0..<frameLength {
            let sqrtV = sqrt(buffer.floatChannelData![channel][sampleIndex*buffer.stride]/Float(buffer.frameLength))
            let dbPower = 20 * log10(sqrtV)
            result[channel][sampleIndex] = dbPower
        }
    }
}
```

There are some calculations (heavy one) involved in it. When I was working on similar solutions couple of moths ago I came across this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5154-avaudioengine-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started there is excelent explanation of this calculation there and also parts of the code that I pasted above and also use in my project, so I want to credit author here: Scott McAlister

Comment: Hmm, is this really correct? You're dividing the sample value by the buffer's **frame length** before drawing the square root... could you explain that? I'm pretty much a novice when it comes to audio...

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Based on @Jakub's answer above, here's an Objective-C version.

If you want to increase the accuracy, change the `deciblesCount` variable, but beware of performance hit. If you want to return more bars, you can increase the `divisions` variable when you call the function (with no additional performance hit). You should probably put it on a background thread in any case.

A 3:36 minute / 5.2MB song takes about 1.2s. The above images are of a shotgun firing with 30 and 100 divisions respectively

```
-(NSArray *)returnWaveArrayForFile:(NSString *)filepath numberOfDivisions:(int)divisions{
    
    //pull file
    NSError * error;
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:filepath];
    AVAudioFile * file = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:url error:&error];
    
    //create av stuff
    AVAudioFormat * format = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initWithCommonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat32 sampleRate:file.fileFormat.sampleRate channels:file.fileFormat.channelCount interleaved:false];
    AVAudioPCMBuffer * buffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:format frameCapacity:(int)file.length];
    [file readIntoBuffer:buffer frameCount:(int)file.length error:&error];
    
    //grab total number of decibles, 1000 seems to work
    int deciblesCount = MIN(1000,buffer.frameLength);
    NSMutableArray * channels = [NSMutableArray new];
    float frameIncrement = buffer.frameLength / (float)deciblesCount;
    
    //needed later
    float maxDecible = 0;
    float minDecible = HUGE_VALF;
    NSMutableArray * sd = [NSMutableArray new]; //used for standard deviation
    for (int n = 0; n < MIN(buffer.format.channelCount, 2); n++){ //go through channels
        NSMutableArray * decibles = [NSMutableArray new]; //holds actual decible values
        
        //go through pulling the decibles
        for (int i = 0; i < deciblesCount; i++){
            
            int offset = frameIncrement * i; //grab offset
            //equation from stack, no idea the maths
            float sqr = sqrtf(buffer.floatChannelData[n][offset * buffer.stride]/(float)buffer.frameLength);
            float decible = 20 * log10f(sqr);
            
            decible += 160; //make positive
            decible = (isnan(decible) || decible < 0) ? 0 : decible; //if it's not a number or silent, make it zero
            if (decible > 0){ //if it has volume
                [sd addObject:@(decible)];
            }
            [decibles addObject:@(decible)];//add to decibles array
            
            maxDecible = MAX(maxDecible, decible); //grab biggest
            minDecible = MIN(minDecible, decible); //grab smallest
        }
        
        [channels addObject:decibles]; //add to channels array
    }
    
    //find standard deviation and then deducted the bottom slag
    NSExpression * expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"stddev:" arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:sd]]];
    float standardDeviation = [[expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil] floatValue];
    float deviationDeduct = standardDeviation / (standardDeviation + (maxDecible - minDecible));

    //go through calculating deviation percentage
    NSMutableArray * deviations = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableArray * returning = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int c = 0; c < (int)channels.count; c++){
        
        NSArray * channel = channels[c];
        for (int n = 0; n < (int)channel.count; n++){
            
            float decible = [channel[n] floatValue];
            float remainder = (maxDecible - decible);
            float deviation = standardDeviation / (standardDeviation + remainder) - deviationDeduct;
            [deviations addObject:@(deviation)];
        }
        
        //go through creating percentage
        float maxTotal = 0;
        int catchCount = floorf(deciblesCount / divisions); //total decible values within a segment or division
        NSMutableArray * totals = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int n = 0; n < divisions; n++){
            
            float total = 0.0f;
            for (int k = 0; k < catchCount; k++){ //go through each segment
                int index = n * catchCount + k; //create the index
                float deviation = [deviations[index] floatValue]; //grab value
                total += deviation; //add to total
            }
            
            //max out maxTotal var -> used later to calc percentages
            maxTotal = MAX(maxTotal, total);
            [totals addObject:@(total)]; //add to totals array
        }
        
        //normalise percentages and return
        NSMutableArray * percentages = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int n = 0; n < divisions; n++){
            
            float total = [totals[n] floatValue]; //grab the total value for that segment
            float percentage = total / maxTotal; //divide by the biggest value -> making it a percentage
            [percentages addObject:@(percentage)]; //add to the array
        }
        
        //add to the returning array
        [returning addObject:percentages];
    }
    
    //return channel data -> array of two arrays of percentages
    return (NSArray *)returning;
    
}
```

Call like this:

```
int divisions = 30; //number of segments you want for your display
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"satie" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSArray * channels = [_audioReader returnWaveArrayForFile:path numberOfDivisions:divisions];
```

You get the two channels back in that array, which you can use to update your UI. Values in each array are between 0 and 1 which you can use to build your bars.